# H264 to TS : Distribution of NAL Units in TS Packets

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mpeg2-ts

I am trying to write ts file without using any library(like ffmpeg or etc.). I added a PAT, then PMT and then all the PES packets. The input-source I am using is a .264 file containing the bit-streams only. There I noticed that, a NAL Unit is generally greater than 184 Bytes in size. But in PES packets I have to make the payload fit in 184 Byte. So what I am doing is, getting 170 Bytes(raw data), adding the header and payload(that 170 Bytes) to form PES Packet of 188 Bytes.

1. Is it the correct way to do that? If not, what should I do?
2. VLC can't play that. That can be a PTS/DTS issue. How should I assign the PTS, DTS and SCR data?
3. I only added PAT and PMT table with only 1 section. Is that enough?

Comment: One PES header per frame. Frames MUST begin with and AUD. Hence one AU will have more than one nal.

Comment: @szatmary, will you please elaborate the distribution of NAL units? I mean, a NAL of size > 184B must be splitted into multiple packets. So how it should be implemented?

Comment: First, Nalus are concatenated with start codes in between o form an AU, then a PES header is pretended, then you split it into 184 byte chunks and present a ts  header to every chunk.

Comment: @szatmary, and what about the adptation field?

Comment: If the ts has an adaptation, the fist packet will have less than 184 bytes of payload.

Comment: thanks @szatmary, I have some more things to ask in this regard.
1. I am keeping NALUs from one SPS to another SPS(not including) in one PES Packet. Is this the right way? I have checked that, in my source(.264 file), I have no AUD.
2.The output that my program produce, can't be played by VLC.
but, ffmpeg can decode the frames from my ts file successfully.
If I just run, ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny_1496402185.ts ppm/ppm_%3d.ppm
ppm files are created .
I have added the PCR_base as 0, pcr_ext as 1, pts as 2 and dts as 1 arbitrarily. Please suggest me how to assign these values.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a traditional chat forum. Each question gets its own page. Open new questions, and I will answer them.